# Create UILabel programmatically and set its position

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, sizetofit

I want to create a UILabel programmatically from a button click and set its position to the x,y coordinates: (50,50).

The text size can vary between 300 characters to 2,000 characters so I'm using:

```
[myLabel sizeToFit]
```

to set the width and height of the label.

This is my code so far:

```
- (IBAction)createLabel:(id)sender {  //create label on button click

    UILabel *label;

    [label sizeToFit]; //set width and height of label based on text size

    //position label
    CGRect frame = label.frame;
    frame.origin = CGPointMake(50, 50);
    label.frame = frame;

    label.numberOfLines = 0;
    label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByCharWrapping;
    label.text = @"This is where the text goes";

    [self.view addSubview:label];     //add label to view
}
```

It doesn't give me any errors when I run the program, but when I press the button to create a label, nothing shows up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not actually creating a label.

```
UILabel *label;
```

Just declares a variable, you never initialise it or assign a value to it. You either need a reference to an existing label or you need to create one using `initWithFrame:`

Also, `sizeToFit` should be done *after* you've assigned the text.

Comment: This worked.  UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] init]; I also added the sizeToFit after the text. Thank you so much! :)